# Best way to sort a big array by a key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have a big array with a lots of datas, here you can have an example :

[image]

Is this example you have only one item `[0]`.

I need to sort this array by the key `date` in `last_message`. (more recently in first)

In `date` i have this format : `"2014-04-23T14:59:53+0200"`

Do you have a good idea for me ? I don't want to foreach i think there is something better.

Thanks !

This is my code :

```
uasort($arrayC, function ($a, $b) {
            if ($a == $b) {
                return 0;
            }
            return (strtotime($a['last_message']->date) < strtotime($b['last_message']->date)) ? -1 : 1;
        });
```

But there is no effect on my array..

Comment: Functions like `uasort` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) allow you to specify a user defined sort function.

Comment: Why did you post a screenshot of your input data? It is better to post it in the programming language you are working in so people can provide code examples and do not have to rewrite from an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php and provide it with a custom function that compares the date.

This would look something like this:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (strtotime($a['last_message']['date']) < strtotime($b['last_message']['date'])) ? -1 : 1;
    }

uasort($array, 'cmp');
```

Comment: With usort it's ok ;) Thanks

Comment: uasort maintains the index of the entry so message 0 will remain accessable by $array[0]. However the order in the array will change so key 2 might precede key 1. You can check this with print_r($array);

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use PHP's uasort() function.  The manual page is at http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php